# How do I determine that key-value storage in iCloud was saved with success?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, key-value

I can simply save value for key in iCloud like this:

```
    let store = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default()
    store.set(value, forKey: key)
    store.synchronize()
```

but how do i know that it was saved with success? Should I keep it somewhere unless I make sure that it is saved? What if there is no internet connection at that time? Will it be synced automatically later?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore):

> Changes your app writes to the key-value store object are initially
>   held in memory, then written to disk by the system at appropriate
>   times. If you write to the key-value store object when the user is not
>   signed into an iCloud account, the data is stored locally until the
>   next synchronization opportunity. When the user signs into an iCloud
>   account, the system automatically reconciles your local, on-disk keys
>   and values with those on the iCloud server.